# What kind of spider is this? And is it dangerous? (photo)

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I found this spider hanging from a web off the side of my house (in Buffalo, NY). It's probably 3-4in total length. Any thoughts on what kind of spider this is? And if it's dangerous?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would think this is a European garden spider (or cross spider). See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_garden_spider) and [here](http://naturemappingfoundation.org/natmap/facts/cross_spider_712.html).
It can bite humans but it is not dangerous for them.

[image]

Comment: Indeed, I recognise it from my European garden. It's not dangerous.

Comment: i think its a cross spider because it doesnt have hair around its legs

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a variety of the very common and diverse group of "garden" and/or "orb weaver" group(s).  They really pop up everywhere during the spring/summer but die off w cold weather (in southeastern US).  Like mentioned, they'll bite but not poisonous...  They're the guys whose webs you're constantly being freaked out by when u hit it face-first---but then never see the spider, or at least aren't bitten normally.
The ones you gotta watch for around here don't make webs that you'll typically see, and either leave their webs often and/or remain in cracks/crevices (e.g.) brown recluse or black widow...).

Comment: If you're in NY- I'm pretty sure you would need be worried only about brown recluse and black widow- if even applicable up there (I'm in GA, so warmer here...).